# Looping through javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop my if statements inside a while loop through my function. But it will only hit the first if statement and stop looping.

Sample:

```
while(No.length == 0 || Name.length == 0 || Tel.length == 0 
      || Date.length == 0 || Email.length == 0) {

    alert("Don't leave blank!");

    if (No.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('Nos').style.visibility = 'visible';
        return false;   
    }

    if(Name.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('Name').style.visibility = 'visible';
        return false;   
    }
    //continues same if statement for rest of the elements variables.
}
```

It will only go to the first if statement and will not loop through it.

Comment: I should ask you as first, what fires your code?

Comment: @Stano fires my code? By a function validate() ?

Comment: Are you calling the validate() function on form submit?

Comment: Yes, stano. Calling through validate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?

```js
function test_all_fields() {
    var No = document.getElementById('No');
    var Nos = document.getElementById('Nos');
    var Name = document.getElementById('Name');
    // ...
    Nos.style.visibility = (No.value.length==0) ? 'visible':'hidden';
    Names.style.visibility = (Name.value.length==0) ? 'visible':'hidden';
    //...
    //continues same if statement for rest of the elements variables.
    if (No.value.length >0 && Name.value.length >0 && Tel.value.length>0 && Date.value.length >0 && Email.value.length>0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Don\'t leave blank!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your version still returns from inside the loop, so it will have the same problem of only iterating once (and then returning).

Comment: it doesn't loop through. Only hits the first IF statement.

Comment: @stano, 'No' is the user input value. 'Nos' is for the error image

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for explaining. I am sure you know how to make it fully functional. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are returning from inside the loop; that breaks the loop.  If you want to continue on to the next round of the loop, use `continue` instead.  If you want to break out of the loop, but not return from the entire function, use `break`.

Now if you are using a jQuery loop, because it's really just a function, you do use return:

```
$.each([1,2,3,4], function(index, x) {
    if (x < 4) return true; // equivalent to continue
    if (x == 4) return false; // equivalent to break
});
```

but that's only for jQuery loops, not Javascript standard ones.

Comment: means return false; continue; ?

Comment: `return true` is the equivalent of `continue` *in jQuery loops*; not in normal Javascript.

Comment: Use `continue` instead: `if (No.length == 0) {`
    `document.getElementById('Nos').style.visibility = 'visible';`
    `continue /*on to the next iteration of the loop*/;`
`}`

Comment: Hi, your statement works but it never stop ending. The error message will keep appearing

Comment: Ok Loop 101 time :-)  When you use `continue` (or just do nothing) inside a loop, it goes on to the next iteration of the loop.  If however you use `break` or `return` inside a loop, it will end the loop.  If you used `break` it will go on to the next line after the loop, and if you used `return` it will go back to whoever called the function.  I don't know what you're specifically trying to accomplish with your loop, but the long and the short of it is you want to `continue` when you want the loop to continue, and `break` when you want it to end.

Comment: So in other words `if(youWantTheLoopToEnd) break`; otherwise do nothing, or if you want to skip processing the rest of the loop use `continue`/

Answer (score 1):

The first error I can see is you should escape your alert with '\' for example :

```
alert('Don\'t leave blank!');
```

And the loop with just continue if you write this :

```
while(No.length == 0 || Name.length == 0 || Tel.length == 0 || Date.length == 0 || Email.length == 0) {

    if (No.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('Nos').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    if(Name.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('Name').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    return true;
}
```

Could also try:

```
while(No.length == 0 && Name.length == 0 && Tel.length == 0 && Date.length == 0 && Email.length == 0) {

     document.getElementById('Nos').style.visibility = 'visible';      
     document.getElementById('Name').style.visibility = 'visible';
     continue;
}
```

Comment: Try adding return true; after the if statements, please see my edited answer.

Comment: no error. It hit the don't leave blank! and then go to return true. Didn't appear my if statements

Comment: So it makes the alert only once? and does not go through the if statements?

Comment: Ya. Only alert once and don't go through if statement

Comment: Sure the while loop has not just stopped?

Comment: i cant try the && because if Name is entered.. the while statement will not go through